# Remove a specific parameter and examples from Swagger Doc

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I have a swagger.yaml file having a lot of APIs. I would like to remove all the parameters with the name of `user-id` from all of the APIs. Also, there are `example`s and `x-example`s which are irrelevant for my use-case that I would like to be removed.

I have been experimenting with `openapi-filter`. However, for it to work I'll have to add a special tag to the parameters and it won't work for examples. I could also be using it incorrectly.

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: action-id
          in: path
          description: Action ID which needs to be failed
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int64
          x-example: 1
        - name: action-category-number
          in: path
          description: Action category number which needs to be failed
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 2
        - name: user-id
          in: header
          description: User under which the action exists
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int32
          x-example: 1
```

Expected output:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: action-id
          in: path
          description: Action ID which needs to be failed
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int64
        - name: action-category-number
          in: path
          description: Action category number which needs to be failed
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int64
```

Comment: You can probably do this using [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do that for examples. `yq 'del(.. | select(has("example")).example)' init.yaml | yq 'del(.. | select(has("x-example")).x-example)' > final.yaml`. Can someone help me with the `user-id` parameter?

Comment: The below worked for me:  `yq 'del(.. | select(has("example")).example) | del(.. | select(has("x-example")).x-example) | del(.. | select(has("name")) | select(.name == "user-id"))' init.yaml > final.yaml`. Would appreciate if someone can shorten it